# MySQL - get users in location between dates

Tags: mysql

I have a logs table that contains logs of entrances and exits of users in a location.

I need to create a query that returns me the following data:

**All users that have been visiting the site between two dates (FromDate & ToDate)**

for this query a user visited the site between the two dates if:

- the user has an entrance log before the **ToDate** but has no exit log at all
- the user has an exit log after the **FromDate** but has no entrance log at all
- en entrance and exit logs exist and the there is an entrance before the **ToDate** and there is en exit log after the **FromDate**

these are some of my tries:

---

```
SELECT UserId, 
       MAX(EventDate) as lastAction,
       MAX(CASE WHEN InOrOut = 1 THEN EventDate END) as lastEntrance,
       MAX(CASE WHEN InOrOut = 0 THEN EventDate END) as lastExit
    FROM site_entrances
    WHERE siteId = 35
    GROUP BY UserId
    HAVING (lastExit IS NULL AND lastEntrance <= '2020-02-17 00:00:00') OR (lastEntrance IS NULL AND  lastExit >= '2020-01-17 00:00:00') OR (lastEntrance <= '2020-02-17 00:00:00' AND lastExit >= '2020-01-17 00:00:00');
```

the problem with this one is: if there latest entrance is after the **ToDate** but an older entrance that is valid in this query exists, it is ignored...

---

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM site_entrances as t, (SELECT site_entrances.UserId, MAX(EventDate) as 'latest'
                                     FROM site_entrances 
                                     WHERE siteid = 35
                                     AND site_entrances.EventDate <= '2020-02-17 09:26:10'
                                     GROUP BY UserId) as maxDate
WHERE t.UserId= maxDate.UserId
AND t.EventDate = maxDate.latest
AND (t.InOrOut = 1 OR (t.InOrOut = 0 AND t.EventDate >= '2020-01-17 00:00:00'))
```

this is the one I used and it works for me. the problem is that it is slow...

---

I think the first one needs a little guidance in the right direction and it would be perfect for me but.
a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Create table:

```
create table site_entrances (
    Id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    EventDate DateTime NOT NULL,
    InOrOut TINYINT NOT NULL,
    SiteId INT NOT NULL,
    UserId VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    INDEX (SiteId, EventDate, UserId) 
);
```

insert:

```
insert into rtls.site_entrances (EventDate, InOrOut, SiteId, UserId) 
values
# entrance before ToDate and exit after FromDate -> valid
('2020-01-02 00:01:00', 1, 35, 'a'),
('2020-04-01 00:01:00', 0, 35, 'a'),

# entrance and exit in range -> valid
('2020-01-18 00:01:00', 1, 35, 'b'),
('2020-01-19 00:01:00', 0, 35, 'b'),
('2020-03-18 00:01:00', 1, 35, 'b'), # not relevant to the query

# entrances without exits but they are befor FromDate -> valid
('2020-01-01 00:01:00', 1, 35, 'c1'),
('2020-01-20 00:01:00', 1, 35, 'c2'),

# entrance before ToDate and exit after FromDate -> valid
('2020-01-01 00:01:00', 1, 35, 'd'),
('2020-02-01 00:01:00', 0, 35, 'd'),

# exits without entrances but they are after FromDate -> valid
('2020-03-01 00:01:00', 0, 35, 'e1'),
('2020-02-01 00:01:00', 0, 35, 'e2'),

# entrance before ToDate and exit after FromDate -> valid
('2020-01-20 00:01:00', 1, 35, 'f'),
('2020-04-20 00:01:00', 0, 35, 'f'),

# entrance before ToDate but exit not after FromDate -> not valid
('2020-01-01 00:01:00', 1, 35, 'x'),
('2020-01-03 00:01:00', 0, 35, 'x'),

# exit after FromDate but entrance  not before ToDate -> not valid
('2020-04-01 00:01:00', 1, 35, 'y'),
('2020-04-02 00:01:00', 0, 35, 'y');
```

the search I'm doing is between the dates: '2020-01-17 00:00:00' AND '2020-02-17 00:00:00'

**the expected result:**

```
UserId | Entrance              | Exit
d      | '2020-01-01 00:01:00' | '2020-02-01 00:01:00'
a      | '2020-01-02 00:01:00' | '2020-04-01 00:01:00'
b      | '2020-01-18 00:01:00' | '2020-01-19 00:01:00'
c1     | '2020-01-01 00:01:00' | NULL
c2     | '2020-01-20 00:01:00' | NULL
f      | '2020-01-20 00:01:00' | '2020-04-20 00:01:00'
e2     | NULL                  | '2020-02-01 00:01:00'
e1     | NULL                  | '2020-03-01 00:01:00'
```

Comment: Provide a fidle, or at least CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO with some sample data. And show desired result for this data. Do not forget to specify your MySQL version. If more than one pair of records per user is possible - show this in sample data too...

Comment: PS. I'd recommend 3 separate queries (for each possible condition) rather than one universal query.

Comment: updated the question with example

Comment: @Dzak post correct sample data. Your current data contain only 2 rows with entrances.

Comment: you are right, sorry. updated the insert query

Comment: What is your MySql version?

Answer (score 0):

Three separate queries:

- both events exists

```
SELECT t1.UserId, t1.EventDate Entrance, t2.EventDate `Exit`
FROM site_entrances t1
JOIN site_entrances t2
WHERE t1.UserId = t2.UserId
  AND t1.InOrOut = 1
  AND t2.InOrOut = 0
  AND t1.EventDate < t2.EventDate
  AND ( @startdate < t2.EventDate AND t1.EventDate < @enddate )
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM site_entrances t3
                   WHERE t1.UserId = t3.UserId
                     AND t1.EventDate < t3.EventDate
                     AND t3.EventDate < t2.EventDate )
```

- entrance only

```
SELECT t1.UserId, t1.EventDate Entrance, NULL `Exit`
FROM site_entrances t1
WHERE EventDate < @enddate
  AND InOrOut = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM site_entrances t2
                   WHERE t1.UserId = t2.UserId
                     AND t1.EventDate < t2.EventDate )
```

- exit only

```
SELECT t1.UserId, NULL Entrance, t1.EventDate `Exit`
FROM site_entrances t1
WHERE @startdate < EventDate 
  AND InOrOut = 0
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM site_entrances t2
                   WHERE t1.UserId = t2.UserId
                     AND t1.EventDate > t2.EventDate )
```

Check them. If everything is correct then UNION them.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a950ec179f722f59644f564a62ca94c6)

Answer (score 0):

With a simulated `FULL JOIN` (because MySql does not support it) to get entrances and respective exits in 1 row:

```
select t.*
from (
  select e1.userid, e1.eventdate entrance, min(e2.eventdate) `exit`
  from site_entrances e1 left join site_entrances e2
  on e2.userid = e1.userid and e2.inorout = 0 
  and e1.eventdate < e2.eventdate 
  where e1.inorout = 1
  group by e1.userid, e1.eventdate
  union
  select e2.userid, max(e1.eventdate) entrance, e2.eventdate `exit`
  from site_entrances e1 right join site_entrances e2
  on e2.userid = e1.userid and e1.inorout = 1 
  and e1.eventdate < e2.eventdate 
  where e2.inorout = 0
  group by e2.userid, e2.eventdate
) t
where 
  coalesce(t.entrance, '2020-02-17 00:00:00') <= '2020-02-17 00:00:00' 
  and 
  coalesce(t.`exit`, '2020-01-17 00:00:00') >= '2020-01-17 00:00:00'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jjRWjULZvFbcwdMysSbWK7/3).
Results:

```
| userid | entrance            | exit                |
| ------ | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| a      | 2020-01-02 00:01:00 | 2020-04-01 00:01:00 |
| b      | 2020-01-18 00:01:00 | 2020-01-19 00:01:00 |
| c1     | 2020-01-01 00:01:00 |                     |
| c2     | 2020-01-20 00:01:00 |                     |
| d      | 2020-01-01 00:01:00 | 2020-02-01 00:01:00 |
| f      | 2020-01-20 00:01:00 | 2020-04-20 00:01:00 |
| e1     |                     | 2020-03-01 00:01:00 |
| e2     |                     | 2020-02-01 00:01:00 |
```